# arc4random_uniform negative 100 to positive 100

Tags: ios, swift, random

Trying to figure out how to make this little ball spawn anywhere from the center (self.frame.width / 2) to (self.frame.width / 2 - 100) and (self.frame.width / 2 + 100)

I found this code on stackoverflow and it seems fine, but my game crashes when the ball is about to spawn

```
ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 + (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(201) - 100)), y: self.frame.height)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated as always <3

Comment: You need to provide more code man, and the point that it is crashing

Comment: also, your question right now is not a Sprite Kit issue,  I would recommend rewording the question or removing the sprite kit tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arc4random_uniform` takes `UInt32` as an argument and returns `UInt32` as well.  Substracting `100` from it will result in underflow eventually, hence the crash.

You can try something like:

```
ball.position = CGPoint(
    x: self.frame.width / 2 + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(201)) - 100.0,
    y: self.frame.height
)
```